# Can I make OCaml produce stack traces on uncaught exceptions?

Tags: ocaml

In Java when an exception escapes the main() function, a stacktrace is printed to the console.  Can you make OCaml programs do the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, compile with -g and set `OCAMLRUNPARM=b`

```
$ cat exc.ml
let f () : int =
    raise End_of_file

let g () =
    f () + 44

let _ = g()
$ ocamlc -g -o exc exc.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b exc
Fatal error: exception End_of_file
Raised at file "exc.ml", line 2, characters 10-21
Called from file "exc.ml", line 5, characters 4-8
Called from file "exc.ml", line 7, characters 8-11
```

Thanks to Daniel Bünzli for pointing out that the behavior can be different if you compile to native code. Here's what I see on my system (Mac OS X 10.9.1, OCaml 4.01.0):

```
$ ocamlopt -g -o exc exc.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b exc
Fatal error: exception End_of_file
Raised by primitive operation at file "exc.ml", line 5, characters 4-8
Called from file "exc.ml", line 7, characters 8-11
```

If you turn off inlining, things seem to work pretty well (at least for this very simple example):

```
$ ocamlopt -inline 0 -g -o exc exc.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b exc
Fatal error: exception End_of_file
Raised at file "exc.ml", line 2, characters 10-21
Called from file "exc.ml", line 5, characters 4-8
Called from file "exc.ml", line 7, characters 8-11
```

Comment: It should be added that stacktraces tend to be more precise if you compile to bytecode.

Comment: You can also use `Printexc.record_backtrace true` to avoid the hassle with setting a shell environment variable, e.g. a line `if !debug then Printexc.record_backtrace true;` somewhere; and `ocamlbuild X.d.byte` target for ocamlbuild, just to be sure.

Comment: @lukstafi, this is very helpful, especially when using `ocamlbuild` to build the project.