# Stack traces from production OCaml code?

Tags: ocaml, production-environment, traceback, debug-information

This explains how to get stack traces on uncaught exceptions:

[Can I make OCaml produce stack traces on uncaught exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613715/can-i-make-ocaml-produce-stack-traces-on-uncaught-exceptions)

Is it feasible to do that in production code?  More usefully, is it feasible to log unhandled exceptions and continue (e.g. with other web requests if in a web system)?

Comment: what do you mean feasible? Like performance hits?

Comment: From my standpoint (of ignorance) there could be any number of reasons why it's not a good idea, so I don't want to guess what they are! :-)  But yes, bad performance is one thing I had in mind.

Comment: Do you expect to have more than 1 uncaught exception every few minutes? If no, then I don't think performance is your main concern.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about problems from the overhead of logging tracebacks, but from debug builds (perhaps optimisation is disabled, etc. etc.).  Just explaining the kind of thing I'm interested in: as I say, I come from a position of complete OCaml ignorance here.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer your question, probably because there aren't enough specifics.

The problem with resuming after an (unspecified) uncaught exception is that it's not clear how much of your process context is still good. It seems far better to me to just let your process fail (and exit), and have a higher-level controlling process start up a fresh new one.

If you don't expect these failures to happen with any frequency (which I would hope is the case), it shouldn't matter too much that this is slower than contininuing to do work in the original process.

If you do this, then the stack trace will just go to the standard error of the failing process. The controlling process can grab it and package it up nicely into a log.

I have built systems like this (not in OCaml) and they work well. How well they work for you would depend on many factors, so I can only suggest that it's worth thinking about.

Comment: Ah, so no specific experience of OCaml?  That's really the part I'm interested in here.  I too have build systems that work like this, just not in OCaml :-)  It is not immediately clear to me that -g builds -- which it seems are required to get tracebacks -- are suitable for use in production (but I'm interested not specifically in debug builds here, rather in logging tracebacks -- the debug build thing just prompted the question)

Comment: You should do some measurement.  Tossing around opinions isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Measurement of what?  The purpose of my question is go get input from the OCaml community on whether this is a vaguely sensible thing to do in the OCaml world, and not specifically on performance.  No measurement will tell me that.